# Problem installing libva (VAAPI), vainfo fails

Tags: 11.10, graphics, intel-graphics, hardware-acceleration, vaapi

I'm following a [wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_VAAPI) on how to make VLC use the GPU in the Core i3 integrated graphics chipset, but I'm stuck at one of the first steps, installing VAAPI.

I installed libva1 and vainfo by using "sudo apt-get install libva1 vainfo", but when I run vainfo it says

```
libva: libva version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

It should say

```
VAProfileH264High               :   VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Advanced            :   VAEntrypointVLD
```

according to the wiki.

/usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so doesn't exist in my system, but I installed libva1 with apt-get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, fixed it after some googling, turned out "sudo apt-get install i965-va-driver" was also needed. vainfo now says

```
libva: libva version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA API version: 0.32
vainfo: Driver version: i965 Driver 0.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Baseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Comment: I have the same issue, however, i965-va-driver is already the newest version (2.1.0-0ubuntu1). any suggestions?  I have Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8 , GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 propietary drivers instaled