# Issue enabling/installing hardware acceleration for ATI Radeon 6600M on precise (12.04)

Tags: radeon, hardware-acceleration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem installing libva (VAAPI), vainfo fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82514/problem-installing-libva-vaapi-vainfo-fails)
>   [How can I enable hardware acceleration for an ATI Radeon HD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87395/how-can-i-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-an-ati-radeon-hd)

I have recently bought a Lenovo Thinkpad which comes with an ATI RadeonHD 6600M GPU. I believe I have successfully installed Catalyst/the fglrx drivers by following the instructions at http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx to the letter. The results of running the command fglrxinfo are as follows:

```
$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
```

These results, to me, suggest that I have successfully installed the driver. To enable hardware acceleration, the instructions tell me I need to install the xvba-va driver. As such, I input the lines:

```
sudo apt-get install xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-x11-1 vainfo
vainfo
```

The output of vainfo is as follows:

```
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

Which is nothing like as suggests on the instructions or the other websites I've checked (which include AskUbuntu and the Ubuntu support pages). I have also followed the instruction about creating a link. I get the following output when inputting the command:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_drv_video.so': File exists
```

This to me suggests the link is not the issue. Any ideas?

Thanks for any/all help provided!

Comment: Please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87395/how-can-i-enable-hardware-acceleration-for-an-ati-radeon-hd)

Comment: Thankyou Kaktarua for your help. I had however already seen that page but it was of no help. However, I did stumble across this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/82514/problem-installing-libva-vaapi-vainfo-fails. The problem I had is simply that I needed to install the "i965-va-driver" package (which was not mentioned on the linked-to page). However, thanks once again for your assistance Kaktarua.

Comment: That is because your system hsa 2 graphic adapters and the one that will support `va` is the one in use, the Intel one. You should post more hardware details in to your question and a proper answer for this bellow. Can you do that?